# How to get current time of video in Mapbox?

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I have added a layer in mapbox with video source. Below is the script:

```
map.addSource("storm-source", {
type: "video",
urls: [
"C:/flood.mp4" // path to our video
],
coordinates: [
[ -79.1680785004, 34.7195831793 ],
[ -78.8680220490, 34.7195831793 ],
[ -78.8680220490, 34.4762734894 ],
[ -79.1680785004, 34.4762734894 ]
] // the coordinates to which your data is clipped:
});
// add this layer to the map
map.addLayer({
    "backgroung": 'transparent',
    "type": 'raster',
    "id": "storm-layer",
    "source": "storm-source",
    paint: {
      "raster-opacity": 1
    }
},
'hillshade_shadow_faint'); // "after" our lowest hillshade layer
```

Now, when the playing position of the video `flood.mp4` has changed, I want to display the current position of the video in seconds. What will be the script for Mapbox? I know two statements-  `var mySource = map.getSource("storm-source");` and `mySource.getVideo().currentTime` can give current time of video for a particular moment but I want to display the current time always/continuously as long as video is running.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `timeupdate` event fired by video element:

> The timeupdate event is fired when the time indicated by the currentTime attribute has been updated.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/timeupdate

Example:

```
var mySource = map.getSource("storm-source");

mySource.addEventListener('timeupdate', function (e) {
    console.log(e.target.currentTime);
});
```

More media events here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events

Comment: Thank you. Actually. I have a button "Start" and when I click the button, video should play. However, I tried it and showing error: index.html:188 Uncaught TypeError: mySource.addEventListener is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (index.html:188)

Comment: Also, I removed the "start" button and tried but getting same error: mySource.addEventListener is not a function.

Comment: Without seeing your usecase reproduced in an exmple. I'de be just guessing here